# SCSS How to use ampersand to get parent context

Tags: sass

I'm not sure this is possible but I feel that it probably is and it's just me doing it wrong. I want to use the ampersand to grab the context of a selector, but I get all it's parents as the context in the compiled CSS, and not just the direct parent. See my gist!

What I would like to do is to give `.product-comparison--ftg__entry` a width of 50% if it's a decendent of `.product-comparison--2`.

[Play with this gist on SassMeister.](http://sassmeister.com/gist/0594b180db322e9260aff1f08e3ef0af)

Comment: I'm pretty sure this isn't possible with Sass out the box. Make a separate rule.

Answer (score 1):

I try to avoid to much nesting and work only with the main identifier. For your case this could be solved like this:

```
.product-comparison {
  &--ftg-entry {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }

  &--2 &--ftg-entry {
    width: 50%;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I will go with this approach then!